# Pyramid: How can I making a static view to some absolute path, and then let users upload files to that path?

Tags: python, pyramid

In my view callable, I want users to be able to create a new file called filename like so:

```
@view_config(route_name='home_page', renderer='templates/edit.pt')
def home_page(request):
    if 'form.submitted' in request.params:
        name= request.params['name']

        input_file=request.POST['stl'].filename
        vertices, normals = [],[]
        for line in input_file:
            parts = line.split()
            if parts[0] == 'vertex':
                vertices.append(map(float, parts[1:4]))
            elif parts[0] == 'facet':
                normals.append(map(float, parts[2:5]))

        ordering=[]
        N=len(normals)

        ...parsing data...

        data=[vertices,ordering]
        jsdata=json.dumps(data)
        renderer_dict = dict(name=name,data=jsdata)
        app_dir = request.registry.settings['upload_dir']
        filename =  "%s/%s" % ( app_dir , name )
        html_string = render('tutorial:templates/view.pt', renderer_dict, request=request)
        with open(filename,'w') as file:
                file.write(new_comment)
        return HTTPFound(location=request.static_url('tutorial:pages/%(pagename)s.html' % {'pagename': name}))

    return {}
```

right now, when I attempt to upload a file, I am getting this error message: `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/path/pages/one'` (one is the name variable) I believe this is because I am incorrectly defining the app_dir variable. I want filename to be the url of the new file that is being created with the name variable that is defined above (so that it can be accessed at www.domain.com/pages/name). Here is the file structure of my app:

```
 env
    tutorial
        tutorial
            templates
                home.pt
            static
                pages
                    (name1)
                    (name2)
                    (name3)
                     ....
            views.py
            __init__.py
```

In my **init**.py I have:

```
config.add_static_view(name='path/pages/', path=config.registry.settings['upload_dir'])
```

In my development.ini file I have

```
[app:main]
use = egg:tutorial

upload_dir = /path/pages
```

Edit: If anyone has an idea on why this question isn't getting much attention, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I feel like you probably have a misunderstanding of how to serve up user-generated content, I will show you a way to do what you're asking. Generally user-generated content would not be uploaded into your source, you'll provide some configurable spot outside to place it, as I show below.

Make the path configurable via your INI file:

```
[app:main]
use = egg:tutorial

upload_dir = /path/to/writable/upload/directory
```

Add a static view that can serve up files under that directory.

```
config.add_static_view(name='/url/to/user_uploads', path=config.registry.settings['upload_dir'])
```

In your upload view you can get your `app_dir` via

```
app_dir = request.registry.settings['upload_dir']
```

Copy the data there, and from then on it'll be available at `/url/to/user_uploads/filename`.

Comment: so in this case isn't that "configurable spot outside to place it" the pages directory? If I make that writeable instead of path/to/writeable/upload/directory will that work? I have updated the question showing where I add the static view.

Comment: and can you explain where you found the use of [app:main] and use = egg:tutorial? I can't figure out what they mean and can't find anything about that in http://docs.pylonsproject.org/en/latest/docs/pyramid.html

Comment: Sure, but in your case you're placing uploads within your source tree, which is really quite frowned upon.

Comment: The `[app:main]` is just your app's section of your INI file. http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/narr/environment.html#adding-a-custom-setting

Comment: so If I were to put config.add_static_view(name='/pages/',path=config.registry.settings['upload_dir']) in the ini file and the put upload_dir=/pages/ would that make the pages directory "outside" of the source tree? If not, can you explain the difference between that and what you have done?

Comment: Well I made it an absolute path to somewhere on the filesystem. So sure, if you wanted `/pages` to be where you store stuff then knock yourself out. Generally your source tree should not be writable by the web server, so storing files there is discouraged. Anywhere else that you choose to be writable is fine.

Comment: Have you read the docs on config.add_static_view? This question is literally just making a static view to some absolute path, and then uploading files to that path. The path is shared between the two code paths by storing it in the settings.

Comment: so how can I make /pages/ be an absolute path (outside the source tree) on the filesystem like upload_dir is in your example? I see no difference between /pages/ and /url/to/user_uploads/filename aside from the fact that the second one is longer. What am I doing differently?

Comment: `/pages` and `/url/to/user_uploads` are URL path prefixes. They have nothing to do with the filesystem. `tutorial:pages/` and `/path/to/writable/upload/directory` are paths on the filesystem. The first one is an asset spec relative to the package, the second is relative to the root of the filesystem (`/`).

Comment: I have been reading the docs on add_static_view and still don't understand why pyramid sees /path/to/writable/upload/directory as path on the file system while /url/to/user_uploads is just a URL prefix. Is it just the /path/ part? Will any /___/___/___(path) that starts with /path/ be seen as a path on the filesystem? Additionally, I have updated the question with my code after your input and the same error exists.